# Why isn't dispatchEvent firing?

Tags: actionscript-3

okay so here is my problem in my main project I'm trying to fire an event using dispatchEvent I've made a simple test class to test this and yet it still isn't working...

Here is the test class

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public function Main() {

        stage.addEventListener("pOver", rake);


        dispatchEvent(new Event("pOver"));
    }


    public function rake(e:Event):void {

        trace("working");
    }

}
```

Why isn't it firing? or why is the listener not capturing that event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dispatching the event on the `Main`, which is a child of `Stage`. If you want to specifically dispatch an event on the `Stage` then use:

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("pOver"));
```

---

Now you may be wondering, "If it's a child, then my event handler should still be getting triggered!"

Well, yes and no.

Lets take a look at a simple diagram of the event life-cycle:

[image]

First, the event that you are dispatching is not a bubbling `Event`. Examining the [`Event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#Event()) constructor, its signature looks like this:

```
public function Event(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
```

Notice that the second argument is by default `false`, which means this event does not perform the bubbling part of the event life-cycle.

Second, you have attached the event dispatcher on the bubbling side of the event life-cycle. If you look at the signature for [`.addEventListener()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) it looks like this:

```
public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
```

Notice the third argument. Which is by default `false` again. This means that you are attaching on the "bubbling" side of the event.

This means that this event is getting to the targeted element, the instance of `Main`, and then stopping and not going anywhere else.

**TL;DR**: *So what does that all mean?*

So to trigger your event handler, *and not change where the event gets dispatched*, you need to change your event that you are triggering to:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event("pOver", true));  // this event will bubble
```

Then your event handler, since it is a child, will be triggered by this event.

Conversely, I think that non-bubbling events will also progress through the capturing side of the event life-cycle so you could also change your event listener to attach to that side of the event as well.

```
stage.addEventListener("pOver", rake, true); // attach to a capturing side
```

I *believe* that event will always flow through the capturing phase, even if they are marked as not bubbling. But I *could* be wrong on that. I just can't remember if "non-bubbling" events skip both capturing and bubbling phases and just trigger the target event phase and I don't have time to check it right now.

---

*Edit*

So, I wrote up a [quick test on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/lQb4):

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {

        private var debug:TextField;

        public function FlashTest() {
            stage.addEventListener("Foo", bubbleFooHandler);
            stage.addEventListener("Foo", captureFooHandler, true);

            trace("Ready");

            trace("---------------");
            trace("Trying a non-bubbling event");
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("Foo"));

            trace("---------------");
            trace("Trying a bubbling event");
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("Foo", true));
        }

        private function captureFooHandler(e:Event):void {
            trace("Triggered \"Foo\" from capturing phase\n");
        }

        private function bubbleFooHandler(e:Event):void {
            trace("Triggered \"Foo\" from bubbling phase");
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this is

```
Ready
---------------
Trying a non-bubbling event
Triggered "Foo" from capturing phase
---------------
Trying a bubbling event
Triggered "Foo" from capturing phase
Triggered "Foo" from bubbling phase
```

Notice that events will always progress through the capturing phase. However, if they are not marked as a "bubbling event", see before, they will descent through the tree they stop when they arrive at target of the event (the `EventDispatcher` the event was dispatched on).

Bubbling events, on the other hand, will turn around and head back *up* the tree.

Hopefully, this clears things up.

Comment: oh so do i have to dispatch the event with the same object that is listening for it?

Comment: Thanks dude! Very speedy reply! Your awesome!

Comment: @MattWilliams you don't *have* to, but if you don't then you need to understand how event bubbling works.

Comment: @32bitkid I think the capture phase is relevant for user interaction events like keyboard, mouse events etc. I don't think custom events go through the capture phase.

Comment: @catholicon both native and custom events have the same event life-cycle. I've updated the answer with some clarification.

Comment: @32bitkid hmm....that's interesting. I was actually thinking of custom events more in terms of an object which is not on display-tree. But, your example sure makes sense. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are listening to stage events. This means that as long as stage is not dispatching any `Events` you will not get any callbacks.

try

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("pOver"));
```